# Jupyter notebook hangs when I try to import PyTables

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pytables

I'm trying to open an hdf5 file so I'm working with PyTables. For some reason the importation of pytables, either with `from tables import *` or `import tables`, causes the jupyter notebook to hang. At first I thought it was having trouble opening the file, but I've set up a bunch of print statements to catch the problem and it came down to PyTables.

```py
print("importing os")
import os
print("importing numpy")
import numpy as np
print("importing pandas")
import pandas as pd
print("importing tables")
import tables
# from tables import *
print("setting path")
path = '/path/to/data'
print("generating empty set")
all_tokens = set()
print("reading csv")
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, 'data.csv'))
print("about to open file")
with tables.open_file(os.path.join(path, "database.h5"), 'r') as h5file:
    print("file open")
    print(h5file)
    for i in range(len(df):
        pass
```

I try interrupting the kernel repeatedly and it still hangs, no error output. The only thing that gets it to stop is restarting the kernel, but the problem persists. Strangely, when I restart, sometimes it hangs on the `read_csv` line instead. The CSV I am importing is fairly large with over 289,000 lines, but there hasn't previously been a problem reading it before. In fact, previously there hasn't been any problem importing PyTables.

If it helps, I'm working in a virtual environment on an HPC via a Slurm job. I have no idea what could be causing this, so any help even in diagnosing the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this "used to work", something changed. :-) pandas uses PyTables for HDF5 access, so it's possible you have a version conflict. You will need to go thru step-by-step to isolate the cause. Execute code 1 line at a time - either with a debugger or running python in the console. Only import os and pd, then call read_csv. (Reading 289,000 lines should not cause a problem.) Assuming that works, THEN import tables and try to open the file. At some point you should replicate the error.